# How can I check my entire parse database

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In order for somebody to login or signup in my application, you must first enter the email address. If you have an account and enter the correct email address it will then take you to another view controller so you can enter your password. If the email address you enter is not in the database, you will have go to through the setup process. If a user enters the email address `JohnnyAppleseed@example.com` I need the Done button to check and see if that is in and based on that it will take them to the appropriate view controller.

So my question is, how can I check my parse database for the email the user enters without having to do it by `getObjectInBackgroundWithId`
Function. Is this possible in Parse?

[image]

Comment: The parse user class automatically checks for a unique email address, if it's in use you get an error and I even think it's in the description.

Comment: So do I even need to enter an object Id?

Comment: If you have a user who signs up with an email address and someone else tries to they won't be able to signup, an error will be returned and it's description will tell you the email is taken. You don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
func checkOrXEmail() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("email", equalTo: self.emailTextField.text.lowercaseString)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (emails, error) -> Void in
        if let emails = emails {
            for email in emails {
                if email["email"] as! String == self.emailTextField.text.lowercaseString {
                //The email is taken    
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Also if you want to check the validity of the email try this...

```
if email.text != "" {
        if validateEmail(email.text.lowercaseString)  {
            emailTaken = false
            if self.emailTaken == false {
                println("Not Taken")
                checkOrXEmail()
            }
        } else {
      // Do stuff  
     }
    } else {
      // Do stuff  
    }
```

Comment: That worked great, but I need it to also check if the email isn't taken! I tried this if email["email"] as! String != self.emailField.text!.lowercaseString {
                        print("That email is avaliable!")
                    } but it is not doing anything. Anyway you could help me out one last time? :)

Comment: @TrentonTyler Yeah! I would love to help you out. Where do you call the method?

Comment: I tried an if else statement after the if email["email"] but that did not work so instead I just created a different if statement that doesn't seem to work either! It might be an easy fix but i'm still learning a lot of new stuff!

Comment: @TrentonTyler Mmmm could you pastebin your entire class? And I can take a look.

Comment: @TrentonTyler Do you have TeamViewer? Because we can use that and I can 1 on 1 help you cause that's easier for me.

Comment: Message me on twitter and I will send you the session id and pass

Comment: @TrentonTyler Ok great

Comment: @TrentonTyler Fixed my answer to show how to validate email.